# What is the hand gesture for shutting someone up?

Tags: gestures

I don't remember what it's called. Not the single finger on the lips but the full hand. I'm writing a story and can't find another way to write. Haha

[image: Not the single finger on the lips but the full hand.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the ***blah-blah*** gesture.

> Blah-blah. The fingers are kept straight and together, held horizontal or upwards, while the thumb points downwards. The fingers and thumb then snap together repeatedly to suggest a mouth talking. The gesture can be used to indicate that someone talks too much, gossips, is saying nothing of any consequence, or is boring.
>   <sub>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gestures)</sub>

If you really intend to convey you do not want to listen to what someone has to say, you can use ***talk to the hand***, or ***zip your lips***:

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2b/TalktoTheHand.jpg][image: http://inchristandunchurched.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/zippedlips.jpg]

But, the more polite way is to use a ***shush***:

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Faras_Saint_Anne_%28detail%29.jpg/220px-Faras_Saint_Anne_%28detail%29.jpg]

---

You added to your question you are wanting to describe this gesture in a story. I would probably describe the hand motion as a ***sock puppet***.

> She made a mock sock puppet with her hand and silently mouthed "Shut up."

Answer (score 3):

I know that gesture best as simply ***"[shut it](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/shut-it)"*** which the Online Slang Dictionary defines as "stop talking".

This gesture was used famously by Dr. Evil in the Austin Powers movies to get his son, Scott Evil, to stop talking:

[image]

Comment: However, Dr. Evil usually said "zip it."